# When can I evolve?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon, pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon

How soon can the player character and partner evolve in Pokémon Super Mystery Dungeon? In previous titles, they could only evolve after the main story has finished, but I'm curious if it's the same in this game or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly it is still the same as the rest of the Mystery Dungeon games and you cannot evolve until after completing the Epilogue. Serebii.net is also full of answers and super
[helpful](http://www.serebii.net/supermysterydungeon/evolution.shtml). Hope this helped!